# SOAP Basic Authorization using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, authorization

We had a web service consumed which was created in SAP. We are able to connect to the service successfully like using

```
var rowss = new EpiCompaniesImplServiceService();  //Service object creation
rowss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

client suggested us to not to send credentials in plain text but in base64 encoded string using user name & password. For that, we have tried to add authorization header by converting credentails to base64 encoded way like below,

```
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(rowss.Url);
string usernamePassword = "username" + ":" + "password";
CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
myReq.Credentials = mycache;
myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + usernamePassword);
```

but it was throwing 401 unauthorized error.
Now client is asking us to try passing with SOAP header. Please suggest me some way to do it by passing encoded credentials through N/W credentials or by passing it through SOAP Headers.

Comment: I think you need to add this line `mycache.Add(new Uri(rowss.Url), "Basic", basic);`

Comment: it was not working like that. Tried that too before it self

Comment: Have you tried setting pre-authentication to true: `rowss.PreAuthenticate = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are just missing encoding in base64:

```
 WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(rowss.Url);
 string usernamePassword = "username" + ":" + "password";
 usernamePassword = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)); // <--- here.
 CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
 myReq.Credentials = mycache;
 myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + usernamePassword);
```

Comment: Timur, thanks for the response but we have tried the above code which i have mentioned with my question with base 64 encoded as you said and in normal way too but, both are not working. I guess there is a need to pass to SOAP Header or through network credentials. Any guessed how to do that?

Comment: Am I right that it worked without base64 and then when you encoded in base64 it stopped wotking?